# How to Allocate running EC2 Instance's non-Elastic Public IP to Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I'm using an AWS EC2 window's instance which has an Public IP. The Public IP is not elastic. The instance runs some app.

Now I've to deploy the app in ubuntu but the Public IP must be preserved. How can I do this?

When I allocate New Elastic IP, I get a random IP address, but I need the existing one which is being used by window's instance.

Is there any way to allocate existing Public IP to elastic IP?

Comment: If you want to draw Amazon attention on this open the issue in Amazon Forums.

Comment: OK, insha Allah, I'll.

Comment: you run your app against an IP ? you should buy yourself a domain and so you will always be able to update the IP (A Address) that points to your app

Comment: I know running app against an IP is not a good idea. But there's a lot of VPN level configuration as we are integrating it with a telecommunication company and the network engineer of that telecommunication company made us using ip address instead of domain. @FrédéricHenri

Comment: AWS forum post regarding same issue : [Can I request a specific IP address for Elastic IP?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=274955)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you will not be able to do that. You cannot convert an AWS Public IP to an Elastic IP. Once you close the server the public IP address gets released. You will have to make the necessary changes to your app to use the new IP address for the ubuntu and this time make sure you use elastic IP for the instance.